# Changing default URL mapping for Serving Static Content in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, web-deployment

My static resources stopped working as soon as I added a new Controller (non rest) in my application with the following mapping

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{postId}/{postUri:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String viewPost(@ModelAttribute("model") ModelMap model, PathVariable("postId") String postId, PathVariable("postUri") String postUri) {
          // do something
}
```

After debugging I found that my newly added controller method started picking up static resources, basically, it has taken precedence over the default mapping for static resources.

For example, Request to the below static resource reaches my controller instead of static resource handler.

```
http://localhost:7999/css/bootstrap-2a31dca112f26923b51676cb764c58d5.css
```

I am using spring boot 1.4

Is there a way to modify the mapping URL for serving default static content since I do not want to modify the URL of my Controller method ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sure thing. There is a `spring.mvc.static-path-pattern` that you can use to override that:

```
spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/resources/**
```

will map `classpath:/static/css/foo.css` to `/resources/css/foo.css`.

(I've made that clearer in [a862b6d](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/a862b6dc79583326bada345d59e492b1aa490b70))

Having said that, I could only *strongly* recommend to change your path there. Having a path variable that catches the root context is *really* a bad idea.

Comment: Spring security is protecting the static resources if we provide a custom value for `spring.mvc.static-path-pattern`, is that intentional? We need not to provide any exclusion patterns in spring security if we do not override the static-path-pattern in spring boot 1.4

Comment: We don't do that. We whitelist usual suspect (that are sub-path) of the root. We can't auto-adapt without creating a security hole.

Comment: I did as suggested, but geeting only ["classpath:/META-INF/resources/"] when calling webProperties.getResources().getStaticLocations().

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content

By default Spring Boot will serve static content from a directory called /static (or /public or /resources or /META-INF/resources) in the classpath or from the root of the ServletContext. It uses the ResourceHttpRequestHandler from Spring MVC so you can modify that behavior by adding your own WebMvcConfigurerAdapter and overriding the addResourceHandlers method.

In a stand-alone web application the default servlet from the container is also enabled, and acts as a fallback, serving content from the root of the ServletContext if Spring decides not to handle it. Most of the time this will not happen (unless you modify the default MVC configuration) because Spring will always be able to handle requests through the DispatcherServlet.

By default, resources are mapped on /** but you can tune that via spring.mvc.static-path-pattern. For instance, relocating all resources to /resources/** can be achieved as follows:

```
spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/resources/**
```

You can also customize the static resource locations using spring.resources.static-locations (replacing the default values with a list of directory locations). If you do this the default welcome page detection will switch to your custom locations, so if there is an index.html in any of your locations on startup, it will be the home page of the application.

In addition to the ‘standard’ static resource locations above, a special case is made for Webjars content. Any resources with a path in /webjars/** will be served from jar files if they are packaged in the Webjars format.

Answer (score 0):

i dint use @EnableWebMVC. This worked for me and spring boot service server static content for default 
localhost:8888/ and also for localhost:8888/some/path/

```
@Configuration
public static class WebServerStaticResourceConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/some/path/").setViewName("forward:/index.html");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added `spring.resources.static-location=file:../frontend/build` in `application.properties`

`index.html` is present in the `build` folder

Use can also add absolute path

`spring.resources.static-location=file:/User/XYZ/Desktop/frontend/build`

Answer (score 0):

For no controller pages:

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/feature")
public class DataTableController {

    // map /feature/* to /feature/*
    @RequestMapping(value="/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView staticPage(@PathVariable String name){
        return new ModelAndView("feature/" + name);
    }

}
```

For static resource except for HTML:

```java
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    // map /res/ to classpath:/resources/static/
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/res/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
    }
}
```