# Spring boot app showing 404 for static files

Tags: spring-boot

I'm having problems with static file in spring boot 
It's a simple example , I used auto configuration

1. Application.properties

   ```
   spring.profiles.active=dev
   server.context-path=/auth
   logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
   logging.level.com.arch=info

   spring.http.encoding.charset=UTF-8
   spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/**


   spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
   spring.thymeleaf.content-type=text/html
   spring.thymeleaf.mode=HTML5
   spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
   spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
   spring.thymeleaf.encoding=utf-8
   ```
2. page-link

   ```
   th:href="@{jquery-1.10.2.min.js}" rel="stylesheet"
   ```
3. Directories

   > ```
   > resources 
   >   static
   >     jquery-1.10.2.min.js
   > templates
   >   index.html
   > ```
4. URLs

   > localhost:8080/auth/static/jquery-1.10.2.min.js
   >
   > localhost:8080/auth/jquery-1.10.2.min.js

Comment: Add this in application.properties
spring.resources.add-mappings=true

Comment: it dosn't work  , 404 again

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41354724/changing-default-url-mapping-for-serving-static-content-in-spring-boot

Comment: Very nice answer @Afridi

Comment: @Afridi done  . I only use application.properties without springmvc configuration , so  the resource handler not be init , and when I add springmvc configuration , it works . thanks

Comment: See the spring documentatiion: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content