# Spring boot not automatically serve index.html after setting spring.mvc.static-path-pattern value

Tags: html, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, static-content

I have checked this post [41354724](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41354724/changing-default-url-mapping-for-serving-static-content-in-spring-boot) and reset the static-path-pattern to `/expense/**`. I am expecting to get index.html when I hit the URL endpoint `/expense/` instead of `/expense/index.html`

Here is my application.properties settings:

```
spring.data.rest.basePath=/api/v1
spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/expense/**
spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/static/expense/
server.port = 8090
```

When I hit http://localhost:8090/expense/, I got

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Mon Apr 09 23:13:21 CST 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

And then when I hit http://localhost:8090/expense/index.html, I do have the file served.

Is there any config from spring that can search for the endpoint and look for the index.html after the static path pattern changed?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `http://localhost:8090/YOUR_APP_ROOT/expense/index.html`? And you probably need to have a folder called expense under static with index.html

Comment: @john yes I do have the folder named expense under static. And I can browse the html file by  http://localhost:8090/expense/index.html, my question is can we get the index.html without the file name in the path (i.e.  http://localhost:8090/expense/)

Answer (score -1):

If you set

```
spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/static/expense/
```

then when you call `http://localhost:8090/` it will render the index.html, if you want to render `http://localhost:8090/expense` then change `server.contextPath` as well

```
server.contextPath=/expense
```